# How to properly use dates in object filters

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm using Django ORM to access database models, it works well when I use `objects.all()`, it returns all the objects in the database.  But when I want to filter on a date I add a filter using the new date type it doesnt return anything, I get a blank QuerySet.  After searching and trying different things for many hours I discovered `object.filter(date__gte=date)` works.

For example:
This works, I get all the records where date = today:

```
today = date.today()
Model.objects.filter(date__gte=today)
```

These do not work, they return empty QuerySets:

```
Model.objects.filter(date__contains=today)
Model.objects.filter(date__startswith=today)
Model.objects.filter(date__date=date.today())
```

My question is what am I doing wrong that one type of query works but not the other, when they should all return the same data?

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish with these filters? Those last three don't really make sense if you think about your datatypes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this([Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#date)) for **DateTimeField**:

```
Model.objects.filter(date__date=datetime.today())
```

If its a **DateField**, then simply do:

```
Model.objects.filter(date=datetime.today())
```

Comment: I tried that and it produces this error:  `Unsupported lookup 'date' for DateField or join on the field not permitted.`

Comment: If its a datefield, then you can simply do: `filter(date=datetime.today())`. Updated my answer. @user500660

Comment: OK, thats works.  But I had to change it to `date=datetime.datetime.today()`.  I changed to using DateField instead of DateTimeField, thanks for your help.